# Using Keyring with laravel

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel

To create an encrypted table the following query can be used:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `intcol1` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intcol2` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcol1` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcol2` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcol3` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ENCRYPTION='Y'
```

How can this be implemented in Laravel.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you, l added the following to the config/database.php: 'engine' => 'InnoDB',
   'encryption'=>'Y'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
//use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
//use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('t1', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('intcol1')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('intco21')->nullable();
        $table->string('charcol1', 128)->nullable();
        $table->string('charcol2', 128)->nullable();
        $table->string('charcol3', 128)->nullable();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->charset = 'latin1';
    });

    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE t1 ENCRYPTION='Y'");
}
```

Side note, BIGINT value can have maximum constraint of 20 so 32 wouldn't be considered afaik.